# Firebase REST auth when creating token with node.js admin sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I know this issue was asked a lot here, but I still cannot seem to find the exact answer that can solve my problem.

I wish to access Firebase using REST calls, by adding an access_token param.

The access_token is created using the Node.js Admin SDK, using the following code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./pk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://XXX.firebaseio.com"
});

var uid = "1234";


admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    // Send token back to client
    console.log("Token: "+customToken);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

The problem is that if I take the token created from Node.js and use it my REST call, I get an `Unauthorized request` error.

I have read in some questions that people added the scope param when issuing the token, but have not found a way to do that with Node.js Admin SDK.

Google's docs are not so detailed with this issue. Any idea what I might try to resolve this one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The token you are using to authenticate to the Firebase REST API is not the correct type of token. You are using a Firebase Auth custom token, which can only be used to authenticate one of the Firebase client SDKs via the `signInWithCustomToken()` method as explained in [Sign in using custom tokens on clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients).

In order to authenticate to the Firebase REST API, you have two options: Firebase ID tokens (for user-based access) or Google OAuth2 access tokens (for admin access).

**Authenticate with Firebase ID Tokens**

See [Retrieve ID tokens on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) for an explanation of how to retrieve access tokens in the various Firebase client SDKs. You can also exchange a Firebase custom token for an ID token and refresh token pair via an undocumented REST API:

**Endpoint:** `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=<API_KEY>`

**Method:** `POST`

**Request Body:** `{ "token": <CUSTOM_TOKEN>, "returnSecureToken": true }`

`<API_KEY>` is the same API key you get from your Firebase Console that you use in the Firebase clients. `<CUSTOM_TOKEN>` is a Firebase custom token.

Since ID tokens expire after an hour, you will need to use the refresh token to refresh them via this other undocumented REST API:

**Endpoint:** `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=<API_KEY>`

**Method:** `POST`

**Request Body:** `{ "refresh_token": <REFRESH_TOKEN>, "grant_type": "refresh_token" }`

`<API_KEY>` is the same API key as before. `<REFRESH_TOKEN>` is the refresh token from the previous API call.

Once you have an ID token, you can pass that to the REST API via the `auth` query parameter to authenticate a request. The request respects Firebase Security Rules as if the end user logged into the client was making the request.

**Authenticate with Google Access Tokens**

To authenticate with a Google OAuth2 access token, the first thing you need to do is get one. See [Retrieving an access token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-get) for an explanation of how to do this. It only currently includes a Java example, but this is possible in many languages, including Node.js. Once you have an ID token, you can pass that to the REST API via the `access_token` query parameter to authenticate a request. The request will be made with admin access, overriding all Firebase Security Rules and granting full read and write access.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, there is no way to get ID tokens without a client SDK (REST of server)?

Comment: Actually, there is an undocumented REST API you can use. I am actually working on documenting this REST API in our official docs, but I've updated my answer in the meantime to get you unblocked.

Comment: Thanks @jacobawenger, but when I try to follow your instructions, I get "Unable to validate signature." after using the id_token as the value for the auth param.. what might be wrong?

Comment: So I understood why I was getting the validation error, as I was trying to test this from an IDE and not from the browser. When I send the REST request from the browser, it works with the ID token.