# Firebase Authentication Server Side

Tags: javascript, firebase, session, firebase-authentication

I am trying to learn how to make a simple authentication application. If I have this in my app.js file,

```js
var logIn = function(req, res) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    console.log("Email verified status: " + emailVerified);
 });
};
```

```js
var doSomething(req, res) {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  // do something with the variable user
}
```

this is not ok, right? Because when multiple users log in, the `currentUser` would just be assigned to the last person who logged in. (Please correct me if that is not true.)

So, I found these:

[How to authenticate a firebase user from server without client side auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626585/how-to-authenticate-a-firebase-user-from-server-without-client-side-auth/46632696)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

They suggested doing something like this:

```js
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)
.then(function() {
  return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
});
```

Does this mean, that adding `setPersistence = None` allows us to use `firebase.auth().currentUser` on the server-side, AKA in app.js, even when multiple users are logged in?

Can we just declare `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)` once in the app.js file or do we need to use promise for each function?

I recently started learning JS and using Firebase. Sorry if some questions are silly. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Firebase Authentication server-side? Generally you won't want to do this -- you'll want to use it client-side and pass the token back to the server. Unless you have a very strong reason, that's what I'd recommend you do.

Comment: "Because when multiple users log in, the currentUser would just be assigned to the last person who logged in." The premise of Firebase Authentication is that (at most) a single user is signed in to your application. If you have a different needs, you might want to consider if Firebase Authentication the the best solution for your app.